# Overlapping divs in liquid layout - CSS

Tags: css, layout, html, liquid

So here's my problem.  I am using a liquid layout on my page, so that the site always fits the width of the window. works perfectly, sounds great, right?  the problem that i'm having is that whenever the window is resized, the divs start moving, overlapping, and wrapping to the next line.

here's my site, so you can see what i am talking about: http://www.kaiserroof.com/test/index2.html

i'm somewhat new to css design.  i'm sure there is an easy fix, but i can't figure it out.  can someone help me? (soon, please.  i'm so ready to be done with this website :) )  Here is my CSS code:

```
html {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 position: static;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #555;
 font-weight: 100;
 line-height: 18px;
}
#container {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 600px;
 background: #eeeeee;
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #555;
 font-weight: 100;
 line-height: 18px;
}
#row1 {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 background: #eeeeee;
}
#row2 {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}
#row3 {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 300px;
}
#row4 {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}
#row5 {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}
#logo {
 float: left;
 width: 13.5%;
}
#phone1 {
 width: 85%;
 float: left;
 text-align: right;
}
#phone2 {
 width: 79%;
 padding-right: 6%;
 float: left;
 height: 54px;
 text-align: right;
 vertical-align: top;
}
#buttonmenu {
 width: 86.5%;
 float: left;
 border: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
#backgroundleft {
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
#intro {
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 padding-left: 15.5%;
}
#form {
 width: 34.5%;
 float: left;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #000;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
 padding-bottom: 76px;
}
#estimates {
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#form1 {
 padding-left: 20px;
}
#welcome {
 width: 34.75%;
 float: left;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #000;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
#linksright {
 width: 30.5%;
 float: left;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #000;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 text-align: right;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 92px;
}
#bottomleft {
 width: 23%;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
#bottommiddle {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
#bottomright {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}
td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: #BBBBBB;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#000;
 line-height: 20px;
}
A:hover { 
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000 
} 
.alternate {
 padding-right: 20px;
}
.object { 
 outline: none;
}
#object { 
 outline: none;
 margin: 0; 
  display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things just can't be wrapped onto a new line, such as form elements. You can hide the problem by setting a `min-width` on each of those columns (#form, #welcome, #linksright), so they won't shrink down past a certain point. Or a larger single min-width on #container, since 600px obviously isn't enough to keep stuff from overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Without the corresponding HTML it is hard to tell. But let me do a guess. As you align many elements using "float" and "width: 100%" they are not in the text-flow anymore. Therefore they might not resize with the rest of the page. On some elements it might be useful to make the use "display: inline-block" instead of "float".

Answer (score 0):

Really I would suggest that you just use a 3 column fixed width layout. Stretching those divs is not going to look good and will make things render weird. Try wrapping the whole site in a wrapper div and then centering it. That way you wont have to deal with the craziness of stretching divs.

```
div#wrapper{
   margin: 0 auto; // this will make everything center automatically.
   width: 960px;
}
```

Sorry to not answer your question but to suggest a different solution. I am just not a fan of liquid layouts.

Comment: i appreciate your response and would consider a 3 column fixed width layout, but here's my problem.  my client wants the site to fill the screen, regardless of screen resolution.  Can i do that with a fixed layout?

Comment: Yeah you can do that for sure. Try looking at some examples on a site like this http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Three_Column_Layouts. You will need to make sure you understand all of the properties for width, float, overflow, position etc... Make sure that you are versed in these properties or you will end up with a really big headache and a nasty looking site. Be sure to check cross-domain compatibility as well.

Comment: @thomallen "I am not a fan of liquid layouts" -- you can always set a max-width on a liquid layout, which will ensure it won't ever stretch too much

Answer (score 0):

You make the two outer columns a static width and make the center a percentage. You can also use a percentages for the left, right margins as well.