# Text overlaps when using liquid layout

Tags: css, css-float

[This possible duplicate didn't help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586353/overlapping-divs-in-liquid-layout-css)

My code is very simple -> [My code, Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QySxLfThkDDV7d0CAtFM?p=preview)

I want my text not to overlap and keep the sidebar percentage as 7%
and the content 90%. 
How can I do that while keeping my layout Liquid?

Comment: you might want to look into using a css reset file to reset default browser styles like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content inside your sidebar is two large and is breaking outside the bounds of the container. If you add overflow:hidden to your sidebar, you will see that only the list items bullets appear.

The margins on the UL are pushing everything outside, also the words will not fit inside a 7% width screen size. You can use the word-break:break-all; css3 rule but it will not work in some browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=word-break

```
.sidebar ul{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if I zoom close enough the text still overlap